# how can set anchor in qt like c# windows form application?

Tags: c++, qt

in the C# windows form application in the control object property panel is an option witch can set the anchor of the control object;
I want sth like that in qt for change the default anchor (top | left)
How can I do this?

in visual studio for c# we can use this :
[anchor in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnbYX.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Graphics/View](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html#graphics-view), you can use [QGraphicsAnchorLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsanchorlayout.html)

```
anchorLayout->addAnchor(textItem, Qt::AnchorLeft, iconItem, Qt::AnchorRight);
```

If you use Qt Quick, [anchors layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html) is much better and convenient to use

```
 Image {
    id: gameIcon
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 12
}
```